# Can CrystalFontz 634 LCD display work with Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-2, display, usb-power

I am running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I have a USB-powered CrystalFontz LCD display model SKD204-634 V2.2 (circa 2004).  I originally had this thing installed in 2 5.25" drive bays of a PC, but decided to keep the display for future re-purposing.

I am able to hook it up to my Windows 10 laptop fine and install the drivers and software to make it do what I want, but really I'd like to make it just display a terminal or some stats from my Pi.

I found a tutorial for a different CrystalFontz display version and downloaded the LCDdaemon (or whatever package) and configured the conf file in `/etc/`.  I tried using a couple of drivers and restarting the daemon, but I don't know where to go from here.

All of the tutorials I found were for XBMC and not Raspbian.  There is also the question of whether or not it's getting enough power.  When I first plugged it in, it seemed to work fine, but then after awhile just started to flicker.  I hope there is a configuration setting I can tweak to make this work.

There is no real purpose to this.  I just want to see if I can make it work and eventually do something cool with it.  Is there anyone with any experience with making a CrystalFontz display such as this work with Raspbian on a Pi 2?

If all else fails, would running it via Wine be an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Wine should never be an option :)

Im not familiar with Raspbian, but i am with Debian and the CFA634.

First you'll need to make sure the CFA634 USB device is being set up properly by the kernel. Best way to do this is to clear the kernel log (dmesg -c), then plug in the CFA634, then check the kernel log again (dmesg). You should see the CFA634 device being detected, and the FTDI driver setup a device file for it. The file will normally be called /dev/ttyUSB0 or similar.

Next you need to edit the /etc/LCDd.conf file.

Youll need to change the Driver=xxxx line in the [server] section to look like "Driver=CFontz".

Then in the [CFontz] section, youll need to use setting similar to the following. Make sure you use the correct device file name.

```
[CFontz]
Device=/dev/ttyUSB2
Size=20x4
Contrast=350
Brightness=1000
OffBrightness=0
Speed=19200
NewFirmware=yes
Reboot=no
```

After that you should be able to start the LCDd daemon (service LCDd start), and the setup lcdproc to display the information you are after (plenty of guides exist on the net).

As for the flickering, yes, that does sound like a power supply issue. Make sure whatever you have powering the rPi is capable of supplying the current the rPi needs, plus enough for the CFA634 (up to 450mA, depending on the specific type of CFA634).